# Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

All of the emails that we are sending out using SFMC contains 50 and above Block bounce(Blocked due to spam or sender reputation issue)

It all started on June 17th up until now. Can someone tell me what to do and how to proceed in resolving this issue?

Comment: This is a deliverability issue. You need to research which ISPs are blocking you and work with them to be removed from those lists. The most likely reason is that you did not follow email marketing best practices, so I would recommend researching and implementing those.

Comment: We rarely have any blocked bounces, but all of our recent sends have registered dozens of them, with our most recent send having 240 blocked bounces. Our deliverability rate typically is between 98-100%, and this week it’s been hovering in the mid-to-high 80s.

Comment: Blacklisting is usually an immediate thing. Without warning it will significantly drop your deliverability. Most do not provide any type of warning or '2nd chance'. You are expected to follow the rules and guidelines and if you do not, they will block you without notice.

Comment: @Gugga Make sure to analyze which ISPs are blocked. Deliverability history does not really matter now. For upcomming sends exclude those domains until the issue is resolved. You can also ask Salesforce to get in touch with the ISP.

Answer (score 5):

This is a generalized and broad question so I would suggest you start off by looking at [Marketing Cloud - Email Deliverability Best Practices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339418&type=1)

> You’ve crafted copy meticulously, made sure your email renders in
>   mobile appropriately and have hit the send button only to see your
>   email be blocked from your recipients’ ISPs. While ISPs are
>   tight-lipped on how they determine whether or not to treat an incoming
>   email as spam or as legitimate mail, the following tips should help
>   ensure that your messages are more likely to be delivered.
>
> Permission is king. Your list should only include those individuals
>   who have opted in. The two primary reasons for this is that many ISPs
>   factor engagement (opens and clicks) with email as part of determining
>   how to treat a particular sender. Another factor is spam complaints.
>   People who haven’t subscribed to your messages are more likely to be
>   unengaged or report your messages as spam. And, depending on your
>   jurisdiction, it may be required by law.
>
> Consider authentication. The Salesforce Marketing Cloud offers a
>   Sender Authentication Package that ties your reputation to a private
>   IP and sub-domain. This keeps your sending isolated from other
>   customers’, and allows you to better manage your sending reputation.
>
> Consider double opt-in. Double opt-in is where a user must take an
>   action with an email – typically clicking a link – in order to be
>   included on your mailing list. The reason you might consider this more
>   stringent permission approach is that it will drastically reduce the
>   number of spam traps and/or invalid or mis-typed email addresses on
>   your list, which could harm your reputation.
>
> Remove unengaged subscribers from your list. As previously mentioned,
>   a large chunk of unengaged subscribers might hurt your reputation with
>   some ISPs. Consider re-engagement campaigns for lapsed subscribers,
>   and if you’re actively experiencing deliverability issues, consider
>   sending only to those that have engaged within the past six months or
>   less.
>
> Have a subscription/unsubscribe page. Most jurisdictions require a
>   working unsubscribe link, and the Salesforce Marketing Cloud provides
>   one out-of-the-box. However it’s also advisable to provide subscribers
>   with options for “opting down” or into other publications, so as to
>   keep complaint rates down.
>
> Warm new IP addresses. Sending millions of messages immediately off a
>   brand-new IP can raise red flags with many ISPs. Take steps to slowly
>   warm your IP and build a positive reputation with ISPs before sending
>   large quantities of messages.

Comment: We rarely have any blocked bounces, but all of our recent sends have registered dozens of them, with our most recent send having 240 blocked bounces. Our deliverability rate typically is between 98-100%, and this week it’s been hovering in the mid-to-high 80s.